# Input validation number with display another block

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, input

I've got the input field, need to check the number only, if value of input is number - another div `.hidden` should `display: block;` Also I've got multiple eventlistener  on four block- onclick this `.hidden` block is visible, if it possible combine this event with the form input event.

```js
;
(function() {
  var amount_list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-row .donate');
  var amount_array = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form-row .donate"));
  var donerForm = document.getElementById('hidden');
  var inputDonateField = document.getElementById('donate-price').value;
  var inputNumber = /^[0-9]+$/;
  var onClickFormVisible = function() {
    donerForm.style.display = "block";

  };

  var amoutn_array = amount_array.map(function(e) {
    return e.addEventListener('click', onClickFormVisible);
  });


  // var onclickInputNumberDonate = function() {
  //     // If x is Not a Number or
  //     if (isNaN(inputDonateField) && inputDonateField.length > 0) {
  //         console.log(inputDonateField);
  //         return onClickFormVisible();
  //
  //     } else {
  //         return false;
  //     }
  // };


  function validateForm() {
    if (inputDonateField === null || inputDonateField === "") {
      alert("Name must be filled out");
      return false;
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <label>Label</label>
  <div class="donate">50kr</div>
  <div class="donate">100kr</div>
  <div class="donate">200kr</div>
  <div class="donate">500kr</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-col doner-price">
    <label for="donate-price">
      only number
      <input type="text" id="donate-price" name="name" value="">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">TExt here</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me now with keyup input event.

```js
(function() {
    var amount_list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-row .donate'); //node-list
    var amount_array = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form-row .donate")); //node-list to array
    var donerForm = document.getElementById('hidden');
    var inputDonateField = document.getElementById('donate-price');
    var inputNumber = /^[0-9]+$/;


    var onClickFormVisible = function() {
        donerForm.style.display = "block";
    };
    var onInputTypeNumber = function() {
        if (inputNumber.test(inputDonateField.value)) {
            donerForm.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    //onclick event for each amount images
    var amoutn_array = amount_array.map(function(e) {
        return e.addEventListener('click', onClickFormVisible);
    });
    //input event only if value === number
    inputDonateField.addEventListener("keyup", onInputTypeNumber);

})();
```

```css
.form-row{display:flex; margin:2rem;}
.donate{
background: #007DBD;
  width: 75px;
  height:50px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
 
}
#hidden{
display:none; 
  width: 100px;
  height:150px;
  background: gray;
  color: black;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <label>Label</label>
  <div class="donate">50kr</div>
  <div class="donate">100kr</div>
  <div class="donate">200kr</div>
  <div class="donate">500kr</div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-col doner-price">
    <label for="donate-price">
      only number
      <input type="text" id="donate-price" name="name" value="">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">Only if Input value === to number.You are see this block;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers support `type="number"`, can also have specified ranges with the `min` and `max` attributes, and can use the `step` attribute to accept only certain numbers (for example whole numbers).

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="50" step="1" />
```

On `submit` of the form, you'll still want to verify of course.
`IsNan()` is useful for filtering out some inputs. Comparing against a regex like `new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');` is a safe bet.

As for:

> if it possible combine this event with the form input event.

I don't quite know what you're asking.
If you are asking how to validate on both `onclick` and `onsubmit` events, just create a function for the validation, like `validateInput()` and call it for `onclick` and `onsubmit`.

```
element.onclick = function() {
  if (isValidInput(inputValue)) {  
    // More code here
  }
}

form.onsubmit = function() {
  if (isValidInput(inputValue)) {  
    // More code here
  }
}

function isValidInput(inputValue) {
  // Check that input is valid
  // Return true / false
}
```

Comment: When user strat type only number on input field, the another block becomes visible. I try to implement it