# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null validation input

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events, addeventlistener

I catch the error:

> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

I've got two events for input and for another div. Nly the input event show this error, how to prevent it? When I add this script to according page when it trigger -all good, but in main.js files I've got this error.

```
<form>
   <div class="form-row">
       <label>Vælg et beløb</label>
          <div class="doner-prices">50</div>
          <div class="doner-prices">100</div>
          <div class="doner-prices">200</div>
          <div class="doner-prices">500kr</div>
   </div>
   <fieldset class="form-row">
        <div class="form-col doner-price">
           <label for="donate-price">
             eller angiv dit eget
            <input type="text" id="donate-price" name="name" pattern="\d+" value="" required>

            </label>
        </div>
     </fieldset>
 </form>   

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var amount_list = document.querySelectorAll('.form-row .doner-      prices'); //node-list
    var amount_array = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".form-row   .doner-prices")); //node-list to array
    var donerForm = document.getElementById('doner-hidden');
    var inputDonateField = document.getElementById('donate-price');
    var inputNumber = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var onClickFormVisible = function () {
        donerForm.style.display = "block";
    };
    var onInputTypeNumber = function () {
        if (inputNumber.test(inputDonateField.value)) {
            donerForm.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    //onclick event for each amount images
    var amoutn_array = amount_array.map(function (e) {
        return e.addEventListener('click', onClickFormVisible, false);
    });
    //input event only if value === number
    inputDonateField.addEventListener("keyup", onInputTypeNumber, false);
});
```

Comment: well one of the elements is null that you are trying to add an event to. So check if the element is there before adding the event?

Comment: What's with all the spaces between `.doner-` and `prices` in `('.form-row .doner-      prices')`? And why this construct with `.map()`? `.addEventListener()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Why do you assign the variable `amount_list`, but then use the same query selector instead of the variable when setting `amount_array`?

Comment: "only the input event shows this error" -- I don't see an input event. I see a click event and a keyup event. If you mean keyup, the problem is obvious: there's no element with `id="donate-price"`.

Comment: @Barmar Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[object NodeList]' is not a valid selector. I tyried convert node_List to array, but I see that can use it only amount_array variable.

Comment: `var amount_array = [].slice.call(amount_list)`.

Comment: You shouldn't give `amount_list` to `querySelectorAll()`. It's already a node list, you don't need to search for it again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583427/input-validation-number-with-display-another-block

I've posted already, it works, but has error